# iOS device restarts with Guided Access Mode turned-on

Tags: guided-access

I have a few iPad, that run an app in [Guided Access Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202612). What happens when a device is restarted due to some reason (like running out of battery)?

Will the Guided Access Mode kick in again when the device starts up, with the same app running?

Is it possible to make it do this if it doesn't work this way by default?

Answer (score 3):

When the device restarts, it will boot up to the Home screen, and **not** into Guided Access Mode with the last configured app.

Apart for restart due to battery draining, anyone can press-and-hold the Home and Power buttons simultaneously and restart the device, despite it being configured into Guided Access mode.

There is no setting in iOS to enforce Guided Access mode between restarts.

Comment: We ended up putting AirWatch on the devices and we can force it into single app mode using that.  Even after a restart.